# Connect to a glassfish server ejb

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I am trying to run a remote client that connects to a glassfish ejb. I followed several tutorials but for some reason i cannot make it work.
This are my jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost = 192.168.0.x
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort = 3700

Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
RemoteMapping p = (RemoteMapping) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejb/MappingBean");
```

When i run the client it stops at ctx.lookup. It remains connected but nothing happens.

Comment: the problem is a line 127.0.0.1 localhost in /etc/hosts

Comment: why are you passing the props file?  Shouldn't it get looked up automatically from the default constructor?